# I have a python project, it runs well under pycharm IDE, while it encounter error when using terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, terminal, pycharm

This is a really interesting problem.

I have a project, which bothered me a lot. The structure of the project is like this:

```
weibo
    __init__.py
    user_info_get.py
task
    __init__.py
    wei_r.py
    request_sleep.py
```

When I run `python wei_r.py` in the terminal, I got an error posted at last. 
I have changed my python 2.7.10 to 2.7.6, it did't work. And what's more, This program run correctly on other same platforms. What's the difference is that i upgrade the OS X Yosemite to Version 10.10.5 . I can't figure out what was going on.
What's the problem?

Here is the code.

1.task/wei_r.py

```
arg = sys.path[0].split('/')
path_add = arg[:-1]
path_add = '/'.join(path_add)

sys.path.append(path_add+"/weibo/")
sys.path.append(path_add)
try:
    from weibo import user_info_get
```

2.weibo/user_info_get.py

```
from task import request_sleep as requests
```

3.task/request_sleep.py

```
import requests as r
import time
```

4.The result :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "task/wei_r.py", line 52, in <module>
import user_info_get
File "/.../weibo/user_info_get.py", line 4, in <module>
from task import request_sleep as requests
ImportError: cannot import name request_sleep
```

5.The last is sys.path printed in the user_info_get.py

> ['/Users/xxx/news/task',
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/xxx/news/weibo/',
>   '/Users/xxx/news']

I must commit that, when i use

```
import request_sleep as requests
```

it run correctly.

Comment: Please show the code you used to add the path and import. The IDE is probably configured to do it behind the scenes for you (just guessing).

Comment: where is the path your terminal point to when you run the python script?

Comment: If `file_b` imports `file_a` and `file_a` imports `file_c`, why are they split into separate packages?

Comment: Edit your answer and put it in properly formatted, please, comments are not very clear. Do you do anything to "add the path"?

Comment: @alexis, ok ,in task/file_b.py, the part code :  #Here we add paths to sys.path list. 26 arg = sys.path[0].split('/')
  27 path_add = arg[:-1]
  28 path_add = '/'.join(path_add)
  29 
  30 sys.path.append(path_add+"/weibo/")                                                                         #Here we import the file from other weibo  directory.                                 31from weibo import user_info_get  #Here is the code from ../weibo/user_info_get.py      #we import the other file from that directory. import time ; from task import file_c as fc .

Comment: @alexis, sorry the arrangement is so bad.

Comment: @Hooting, the path equals the file path, where the file located.

Comment: @Trengot, The reason for splitting the file is that they belong to different models.

Comment: @hello_god, add the code to the question, not comments

Comment: @alexis, sorry i was adding a comment to it then.

Comment: @hello_god I've tried to add to the question, please check it matches what your code looks like.

Comment: @Trengot,  i have added the important codes.

Comment: @alexis, i have added the codes.

Comment: @alexis, hello, i really appreciated you if you help me out. Thanks.This is my first question in the stack overflow forum.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't tell what's going on. Please edit your question again: half of it is about `Dir_A` and `fileA.py`, half is about `weibo` and `wei_r.py`. Show the actual directory structure, maybe print out and report the value of `sys.path` after the modifications, and someone (probably not me) might be able to help. To get help, the key is to write good and clear questions. Keep working on it!

Comment: @alexis, i will print all the sys.path and you will see it.

Comment: @alexis , Thank you any way.

Comment: task isn't a module, it's a folder, it appears to me.  You import from modules not folders, so `from task import request_sleep as requests`  is bound to fail.

Comment: @saulspatz, sorry i have a __init__.py in the task and weibo directory.

Comment: @hello_god  Sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: Thanks, looks better now. Thanks to your persistence (and as a reward for it), I can reproduce the error *with python 2.7*, but with python3 it runs successfully. Perhaps someone familiar with the minutiae of relative imports can explain what's going on?

Comment: @alexis, This program can run on some python2.7 environments, but can't run on some other python 2.7 environments. That's weird.